# Record the history of redirect page

Tags: arrays, redirect

I need help on page redirection. This is what im trying to achieve.
1. When a user Goes to my original Link he will be redirected to another page
2. On that page, when the user click on the back button he needs to be back on the original link.

as of now, when the user is on the 2nd page the back button is not available. How can I record the history of my original redirect link? Thanks! Here is my code:

```
<script>
var randomlinks=new Array("http://google.com", "http://nba.com", "http://facebook.com", "http://cnn.com", "http://www.geocities.com");
location.href = randomlinks[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomlinks.length)];
</script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On the second page you can use the `history.back` method to navigate back to the first page. `-1` will go back one page.

```
window.history.back(-1)
```

Comment: Okay Thank you! let me try this.

Comment: I tried it but it is automatically redirecting the page back to the first page. What Im trying to do is when the user click the back button on the browser they will be redirected to the original link.

Comment: @EdsonRosaroso so the first page is not the original link?

Comment: Yes the first page is the original link but it should be redirecting automatically. The user should click the back button and then redirect back to the original link